# JavaFX Scenebuilder 2.0 move Labels etc. into Parent Container

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I am trying to move my labels etc. (see image) from pane to the scroll pane, but I cant figure out how to do it and also I am not able to find something helpful on google.

I refuse to believe that there is no such function! Can someone help quick?

[image]

Thanks.

P.S. I am doing this because otherwise I am getting a `NullPointerException` when trying to call the ScrollPane, because all the Labels etc. are in Pane.

Comment: Nevermind guys, Scenebuilder is retarded, it didnt saved (or unsaved) the controller, that caused the Error... but still would like to know how to move these objects to parent container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have multiple content nodes of a ScrollPane.

The reason for this is that the [content](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html#contentProperty) property of a ScrollPane is a single node and not a child list.

So, the restriction is in the JavaFX API and not really in SceneBuilder itself, which just allows you to define layouts that conform to the available API.

I don't really see it as a restriction as the solution is simple, just set a parent node such as a layout pane or group as the content of a ScrollPane and add your children to the parent node.  This is what you have already done.

In general though, if you had a different set of parent nodes, such as multiple panes (which is not your case here) and you wanted to move children around in SceneBuilder, you can just drag and drop them from one Pane to the other.

Comment: Yeah I had it, the error came from an other source (see my comment under the main question). Thanks for your answer!